# Calculations in Birkhoff's theorem proof

Tags: solution-verification, lattice-orders

I am reading the proof of Birkhoff's theorem (from T.S. Blyth - Lattices and Ordered Algebraic Structures-Springer (2005), page -$68$) which states that

> **A lattice $L$ is distributive if and only if it has no sublattice isomorphic to either of $M_3$ and $N_5$. Equivalently, $L$ is distributive iff the cancellation laws hold in $L$.**

Here to proof the converse part, the writer defined for given any
$a,b,c\in L,\quad a^*=(b\vee c)\wedge a,\quad  b^*=(c\vee a)\wedge b,\quad  c^*=(a\vee b)\wedge c$.

Then he claimed that it is obvious to have
$a^*\wedge c^*=a\wedge c, \quad b^*\wedge c^*=b\wedge c,\quad a^*\wedge b^*=a\wedge b\tag{1}$

Then he considered $d=(a ∨ b) ∧ (b ∨ c) ∧ (c ∨ a)$ and showed using modularity twice,
\begin{align}
a^* ∨ c^* &= a^* ∨ [(a ∨ b) ∧ c]\\
&= (a^* ∨ c) ∧ (a ∨ b)\quad [\text{since}\quad a^*\le a ∨ b]\tag{2}\\
&=\left([(b ∨ c) ∧ a] ∨ c\right)∧ (a ∨ b)\\
&= (b ∨ c) ∧ (a ∨ c) ∧ (a ∨ b) \quad [\text{since}\quad c \le b ∨ c]\tag{3}\\
&= d
\end{align}

Now I'm facing problems to understand why $(1),(2),(3)$ are happening. Any help for the calculations for $(1)$ and the reasons for $(2)$ and $(3)$ is highly solicited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) holds by absorption:
\begin{align}
a^* \wedge c^* 
&= (b \vee c) \wedge a \wedge (a \vee b) \wedge c\\
&= ((b \vee c) \wedge c) \wedge (a \wedge (a \vee b))\\
&= c \wedge a,
\end{align}
and analogously for the other two identities.

While I don't know exactly the context of this proof, it seems likely that it is already assumed that the lattice is modular, and so (2) and (3) follow from modularity.

Comment: I've just updated my question. yes modularity was used twice. but where was it used?

Comment: In (2), from $a^*\leq a\vee b$ conclude that $a^*\vee((a\vee b)\wedge c)=(a\vee b)\wedge(a^*\vee c)$, and analogously in (3). It's a straight application of the modular law.

Comment: as far as I can see, distribution law is used in the 2nd line... $a^*\vee(a\vee b)=a\vee b$ for which the logic is $a^*\le a\vee b$. but why is so?

Comment: @ManjoyDas You don't need that to conclude that $a^*\leq a \vee b$. It follows by transitivity: by definition, $a^*\leq a\leq a\vee b$.

Comment: @ManjoyDas There are [other ways](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) to acknowledge those who help (for this question or other for which you might think there's a helpful answer).